# What are fusion stones?

Tags: runes-of-magic

Fusion Stones are confusing, not only is it hard to find them but I don't even know what they do. Can someone explain how they work, and what they are used for?

Answer (score 1):

Fusion stones are used to create Manastones of the tier the item is from. Secondly you can take stats from equipment to pimp up your own. But always remember, the gear you get the stats from is always destroyed

Comment: can u elaborate on the different types of fusion stones please?

Answer (score -5):

i believe for me this was the best explanation i could find , and really very very helpful http://romguides.blogspot.nl/2010/07/creating-mana-stones.html

Comment: Please don't leave link only answers.  Provide all the information asked by the question, and then link back to your source.